# CosmosDB spatial index creation - bug?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, spatial-index

I create a container (using CosmosDB Emulator) and then want to add a spatial index for a Point property that will be present within my documents.  I am using the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos (C#) SDK to create the spatial index, i.e.:

```
// Clear any existing spatial indexes ...

container_properties.IndexingPolicy.SpatialIndexes.Clear();


// Add a spatial index for the geopoint (Point) property ...

spatial_path = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.SpatialPath();

spatial_path.Path = "/geopoint/?";


// Add Point index type ...

spatial_path.SpatialTypes.Add( Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.SpatialType.Point );

container_properties.IndexingPolicy.SpatialIndexes.Add( spatial_path );


// Update the container ...

container_response = await m_container.ReplaceContainerAsync( container_properties );
```

The code above executes successfully.  However, when I examine the spatial indexes created via the Emulator, the following is shown:

```
"spatialIndexes": [
        {
            "path": "/geopoint/?",
            "types": [
                "Point",
                "LineString",
                "Polygon",
                "MultiPolygon"
            ]
        }
```

**Question** - Why are the "LineString", "Polygon" and "MultiPolygon" types shown when the code only specified / added the "Point" type?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why are the "LineString", "Polygon" and "MultiPolygon" types shown
> when the code only specified / added the "Point" type?

This is not a bug in the SDK. It is by design. From [`Index geospatial data with Azure Cosmos DB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-geospatial-index) documentation page (emphasis mine):

> Azure Cosmos DB supports indexing of Points, LineStrings, Polygons,
> and MultiPolygons. **If you index any one of these types, we will
> automatically index all other types**. In other words, if you index
> Polygons, we'll also index Points, LineStrings, and MultiPolygons.
> Indexing a new spatial type does not affect the write RU charge or
> index size unless you have valid GeoJSON data of that type.

Comment: Thank-you for the doc reference.  Some sample (code) and the SDK imply individual spatial index types can be configured, which leads to some confusion.  If I understand correctly by simply adding a spatialIndexes path of "/*" CosmosDB will index ALL spatial types found in a document.

Comment: I also thought that and wondered about the same when we implemented this functionality in our application. Thanks to you I finally read the documentation and got my confusion cleared (+1 for your question because of this).

Comment: Yes - the doc reads: "If you specify an indexing policy that includes a spatial index for /* (all paths), then all data found within the container is indexed for efficient spatial queries." -- but if you add a specific path name for a spatialindex, i.e.: "/location/*" - does this mean ALL GeoJson properties (paths) will be indexed or just this specific path?   I guess the only reason to include a specific property name is if one were to EXCLUDE it from being indexed?